# Assemble classpath for Junit Platform Console Runner

Tags: classpath, junit5

I have a project using Maven + Webdriver4 + JUnit5.

I want to execute some of my tests using JUnit5 console runner (junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar). The tests are under src/test/java folder, foo.bar package. My dependencies are in the regular Maven .m2 folder.

I'm having some problem assembling the classpath:
`java -jar "<path_to>\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar" -cp <?classpath?> --select-class foo.bar.TestToRun`

I need to have two items on the classpath:

- the dependency JARs in .m2 folder
- the test classes in target\test-classes folder

As a dummy solution, I exported the content of my classpath: `String cpString = System.getProperty("java.class.path");`

Then I manually added the content and executed the command:
`java -jar "<path_to>\junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar" -cp "<cpString_content>" --select-class foo.bar.TestToRun`

But I'm sure there is a better way to get the classpath content.

I tried saving the content to a file using Maven dependency plugin (build-classpath). But it looks like `test-classes` folder is not added to the output, therefore my test class is not found when executing above command.

Is there a better way to assemble the classpath that contains both dependency JARs and test classes?

Comment: Since you’re obviously using Maven dependencies why not use Maven or Gradle to run your tests in the first place?

Comment: You're right, that's an option. Actually, it's not a live project, I'm just exploring JUnit5 features and using one of my pet projects. So I'd like to use the console runner to see if it's a feasible option with a Maven project.

Comment: Getting the classpath w/ all direct and transitive dependencies right is one of the main reasons that tools like Maven and Gradle exist. If you don’t use them, you’re mostly on your own.